# Set content-type on blob

Tags: javascript

We're transferring a `Blob` (image) down a websocket and rendering it to a canvas on the other end.

When I use `createObjectURL` with the blob, I get this warning:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "blob:https%3A//example.com/demo".
```

We create the object URL using the following code. The blob is send via a standard websocket with `socket.binaryType = "blob";` on the client side:

```
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
  var blob = e.data;
  var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);

  var image = document.createElement('img');
  image.src = url;
}
```

The only way I can think to address this warning is to create a copy of the blob with the following code, but I don't want to introduce the overhead of copying all the data:

```
var blob = new Blob([e.data], {
  type: 'image/gif'
});
```

The method gets called dozens of times per second.

Any ideas on how to set the blob content-type without creating a duplicate `Blob` object with `new Blob`?

Comment: Can you show how you send the blob data? Notice that the `.binaryType` property only takes effect on binary message - if you're sending text, the `event.data` will always contain a string.

Comment: It's very simply: `socket.send(message);` at the Node JS end. `message` is a binary blob object coming from an OSX app via SocketRocket (`NSData` type). The message is definitely a binary `blob`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Let's consider you have [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) instance (`blob`). You can use then `slice` method on it:

```
blob = blob.slice(0, blob.size, "image/jpeg")
```

and that's it.

It just creates a new blob with the same data, but with the new type.

Comment: nice hack to change type of blob when its readonly propertie.

Comment: Be careful! This does not work in Safari. (Especially if you want to load a video dynamically.) You need to create a new instance: `blob = new Blob([blob], { type: "video/mp4" });`

Comment: @progmem ale you 100% sure?

Comment: @turkus Yes. I just had to deal with that bug. I needed to dynamically load a video and Safari reported incompatible content (because the type was not recognized) until I changed this exact line of code from `.slice(...)` to `new Blob(...)`.
Safari really is the new Internet Explorer.

Comment: @progmem :) which version?

Comment: @turkus Version 14.0.2 (16610.3.7.1.9).

Comment: You saved me a couple of days. Thank you so much @turkus

Answer (score 6):

First I would wonder if when you say "error" you actually mean "warning".  They are really two different things and the browser treats them differently (it usually only tracks/raises warnings when the developer tools are open etc).

So first I would challenge the premise that this is even an issue ( the overhead of the browser "auto-typing" the blob versus the overhead of "newing" up a Blob etc ).

But, that said, the blob.type property is indeed inmutable in JavaScript and as such you have to set it when the blob is "newed".  In your case it sounds like you are getting the data from a Objective-C socket and just daisy chaining it down via:

```
ws.send(fromObjectiveCSocket, {binary: true, mask: true});
```

The blob data itself from the Objective-C socket is not containing the "header" type data of the type when it sends it across, and it sounds like your node is not touching the blob at all (have you tried decorating the new Blob in your node and then sending that down the socket to see if it retains the typing?).

So what is happening is that the websocket is sending down just the blob data as it got it and when the receiving javascript gets it, it is implicitly typing it with a new Blob right then and there, just with a blank type.

So essentially no, there does not seem to be any way around the new Blob construction if you really want to get rid of this warning.  Even if you tried tricks like adding the type into the blob data and then splicing it out etc, you still can't get around the websocket receiving code implicitly typing it as a blob with a blank type.

Comment: Cool, thanks! You're spot on with your assumptions re: error vs. warning (and I've updated my question), and re: daisy chaining the binary data from Objective-C, through Node, and on to the client :) I haven't tried decorating the new Blob in Node. What's the best way to try that? If there has to be a duplication, best to have it on the high-performing server. That could work. I'm currently setting the `type` in Objective-C with `CGImageDestinationCreateWithData` (type `kUTTypeGIF`) but doesn't seem to go through.

Comment: @ChrisNolet - by decorating it on the server I meant trying to new Blob() it in the node and actually setting the type, then seeing if the blob you get down out of the socket retains the type... I'm pretty skeptical about that though, specially when using the binary socket, bet it only passes the data so the browser would still "type" it anonymously.

Comment: Yeah, fair call. I had a shot at creating a blob on the server-side but Node doesn't support `blob` natively. Any further thoughts on that?

Comment: Have you tried what the size difference is between sending down the raw binary blob of the image as {binary: true, mask: true} and sending down the Base64 encoded version of that blob as a normal string message?  If the size isn't to much different it should be possible to just use that base64 image in the browser instead of the blob url.  Also that's more supported than blob URLs and would take less memory potentially.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should set your Content-Type on the server side before sending it

Comment: Hi @Adassko. Have tried that but the type property doesn't seem to be mutable. Doing `console.log(e.data)` both before and after setting `e.data.type = 'image/gif'` reveals that the property doesn't change. Have added some more code to the question.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this by myself and edited my answer. Your code with creating a new Blob with a copy of content doesn't work neither even when you decide to use it

Comment: Interesting - have tried the proposed (memory intense) solution in my question and it works okay on Chrome v29, although admittedly I haven't tried it on other browsers yet.

Answer (score 0):

"Blob URLs only work with GET requests, and when one is successfully requested, the browser sends an HTTP 200 OK status code and also sends a Content-Type header that uses the type property of the Blob."

```
 var bb = new BlobBuilder();
 var blob = bb.getBlob("x-optional/mime-type-here");

 //send via websocket
 //load via websocket
```

Am I completely off here?

I've gotten all of this from https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-22/blobs

HTML5 Rocks seems to be making a new Blob with the response from the XHR request. So maybe it isn't so bad after all. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-response

Just throwing out some ideas.

Comment: Thanks Sheng for the ideas. I believe you could achieve something similar to my `new Blob()` solution using BlobBuilder, however this is not obsolete: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BlobBuilder, and would still require copying memory from an `ArrayBuffer` (websocket data) to the blob - I believe.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem from the end you are delivering the image. This problem is happening because of the wrong content-type, so you should configure your server to send image with image headers.

If this was in PHP, you should have something like

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $image_blob;
exit;
```

*(Just giving you an idea)*

In case of Node.js, though I am not an expert you can set the content type on the response object like:

```
app.get('/image.gif', function(req, res) {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'image/gif');
  res.sendfile('./image.gif');
});
```

Comment: Sounds cool. I'm using Node.js and just sending the data with `socket.send(message);` via the `ws` package (version 0.4.x). The message is originally just a binary packet from another websocket originating in Objective-C. Any ideas on how to set the `Content-Type` in this scenario?

Comment: Thanks @Starx. Looks like this is for `GET` requests. In this case it's all websockets with `socket.binaryType = 'blob'` ;)