# How to generate an Excel file from a blob

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, blob

From my backend I'm receiving a blob. I'm trying to convert it back to an Excel file. However, in my Excel file I see `[object Blob]`.

How can I decode the blob back to text/string?

I expected to get a bunch of arrays, instead I received a blob object.

The file structure I expect is as follows:

```
[bert, 38, new york]
[adam, 32, florida]
[hannah, 28, london]
```

This is what I have tried.

```
AbsentiesService.getCsvByGroep(emptyQuery, groepId).then((response) => {
  // is blob octet-stream
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([response.data], {
      type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    }),
  );
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', 'file.xlsx');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
});
```

Comment: If `response.data` _is_ a blob, why not just directly serve that? `URL.createObjectURL( response.data )`? If the type isn't correct yet, this answer seems to be useful to you as to how to change the blob type: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50875615/2991619 - So it would be `URL.createObjectURL( blob.slice(0, blob.size, "application/vnd.ms-excel") )`. Also, I highly doubt that an excel file will come out as readable text, as Excel stores in binary format, and I don't think there's much you can do. If the structure you mentioned above is correct, maybe consider a `.tsv` or `.csv` file instead.