# Streaming a MediaRecorder Blob via Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, web-mediarecorder

On a browser, we have created a `MediaRecorder` instance and are using it to record audio. When we stop recording we're then trying to upload the data (which is a Blob at this point) to a NodeJS service that then writes the data to a file.

The upload works, but the file written to the server is not a valid audio file.

We're writing the file up a Socket.IO socket like this:

```
  recorder.ondataavailable = async (chunk) => {
    console.log(`Mime type: ${recorder.mimeType}`);
    console.log(`blowing chunks`);
    chunks.value.push(chunk.data);

    const result = await socket.emitWithAck('data', chunk.data);
    console.log(result);
  };
```

and on the server receiving it like so:

```
  socket.on('data', async (data: Buffer, ack) => {
    try {
      writeFileSync('data/testfile.ogg', data);
      ack('saved');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      // throw (err);
    }
  });
```

(We've also tried `appendFile` but the client's 'ondataavailable` only gets fired when we stop the recording at the moment so it makes no odds to use append or write, write saves us from deleting the file manually all the time.)

The media type of the audio is `audio/ogg`, according to MediaRecorder.mimeType.

The size of the data client & server side are the same so it doesn't look like it's missing some of the data when it's saving.

What is the correct way, with NodeJS, to save binary data that should be an encoded ogg audio file?

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is late, but according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/send:

> Specifying a Blob enqueues the blob's raw data to be transmitted in a
> binary frame (the Blob.type is ignored). The value of bufferedAmount
> is increased by the byte size of that raw data.

You will therefore have to add the mime type back to the raw data. Here is the accepted answer to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50875615/1079320